# Proving $e^x < (2x + 1)\frac{x^x}{x!}$ to conclude $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[x]{x!}}{x}=\frac{1}{e}$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

> The question is to prove an inequality:
> $$e^x < (2x + 1)\frac{x^x}{x!}$$
> Conclude from it that:
> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[x]{x!}}{x}=\frac{1}{e}$$

I've tried to play around derivative of left hand side,

\begin{aligned}
e^x - (2x + 1)\frac{x^x}{x!} < 0
\end{aligned}

But I couldn't find a good way to solve this problem. Can someone help me with this one? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $x! = \Gamma(x+1)$ for $x \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Inequality is false for $0  < x \leq 0.62002{\dots}$.  Can you show the inequality is true for $x = 1$? and that the derivative of the left-hand side of the inequality is less than the right-hand side?  (Can you then apply the FTC to $$  \mathrm{e}^1 + \int_1^x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\mathrm{e}^t \right) \,\mathrm{d}t < (\text{right-hand side at $x = 1$} + \int_1^x \text{derivative of right-hand side} \,\mathrm{d}t  \text{.)}  $$

Comment: @EricTowers After seeing your answer, I delete my own simple answer.

Comment: That math problem was regarding to one of the chapter about higher order derivatives (single variable). I also tried something with Maclaurin's or Taylor's series but no luck. We didn't learn about integrals at course yet, so I'm not sure that it is something about it.

Comment: @Matthew By $x!$, do you mean $x$ is a positive integer? Or, do you mean $x! = \Gamma(x + 1)$ for a real $x$?

Comment: @RiverLi Positive integer

Comment: @Matthew If $x$ is a positive integer, prove that $(2x + 1)\frac{x^x}{x! \mathrm{e}^x} <(2x + 3)\frac{(x + 1)^{x + 1}}{(x + 1)! \mathrm{e}^{x + 1}}$.